# Let $f$ be the function $y\mapsto (1−y^3)/y$ on $(0,\infty)$. Show that $f$ is decreasing (without using derivatives)

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt:
Let $x=1$, $y=2$.
$2>1$, $f(1)>f(2)$ so true for $x=1$, $y=2$.

Then let $x=u$, $y=v$
If $v>u$, $v=x+p$

I've then subbed them in but got $p(3u^2 -1)<3u^2$ which doesn't tell us anything.

Am I allowed to say that as $u$&$p$ are positive $1/u > 1/(u+p)$, and $1-u^3> 1-(u+p)^3$ so it's true for $1$&$2$, $u$&$v$ so true for all others?

Comment: Please use MathJax in future.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

For $y>0 $

$$f(y)=\frac{1-y^3}{y}=\frac{1}{y}-y^2$$

What about the sum of two decreasing functions ?

Comment: So sum of 2 decreasing functions is also decreasing, but surely I then need to prove that they are both decreasing too?

Comment: @HistoryFan12 What about the inverse and the opposite of an Increasing function.

Comment: So... you can kind of say these things without proof, just stating they are the inverse and opposite? @hamam_abdallah

Answer (score 0):

For
$\dfrac{1-y^3}{y}
$,
on $0, \infty$,
$y$ is increasing and positive 
so $y^3$ is increasing
so $1-y^3$ is decreasing
so
$\dfrac{1-y^3}{y}
$
is decreasing
since a decreasing function
divided by a positive increasing function
is decreasing.

Comment: I get that this is a fact, but does what you've written count as proof?

Comment: If you write it out formally (e.g., $f$ increasing means $x < y \implies f(x) < f(y)$) it does, at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<x<y$. Then $-xy(x+y)$ is negative, hence less than  $1$. This gives $(y-x)[-xy(x+y)] <y-x$ or $xy((x^{2}-y^{2}) <y-x$.  This gives $x-xy^{3} <y-x^{3}y$ which says $f(y) <f(x)$.